# Python - can't parse utf8 csv

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8

I tried to use `csv` module to parse csv file, but it does not handle utf-8 encodings.

So I tried these methods that were suggested in documentation:

```
def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')
```

But if I try to use it like that:

```
with open(u'spam1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = unicode_csv_reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        print row
```

I get this error:

```
yield line.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But if I open that file with libreoffice, it opens that csv file with utf-8 encoding fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is meant to be used on **unicode values**; e.g. you need to decode your data to `unicode` before passing it in to the replacement reader.

Use `io.open()` read the data as Unicode:

```
import io

with io.open(u'spam1.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    spamreader = unicode_csv_reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        print row
```

This basically temporarily encodes unicode to UTF8 for the CSV module to handle.

Because your data is *already* encoded to UTF8, you could get away with:

```
with open(u'spam1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        row = [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
```

as well; so directly decode your row cells from UTF8 without decoding to Unicode first, then encoding again to UTF8 bytes then decoding again.

Comment: Thanks. This helped, just needed to change `rb` to `r`, as it didn't let me use that option. I thought `u` option already opened as unicode.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. No, `u` stands for 'universal line ending mode' instead.

Comment: The second option you provided gives me this error:     `row = [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

Comment: @Andrius: Note that I don't use `io.open()` and `unicode_csv_reader()` there! That example reads bytecode with the regular standard `open()` function, passing it directly to `csv.reader()`.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that you switched from unicode_csv_read(). Thanks both solutions are good.

Comment: Alteratively, you can `pip install unicodecsv` and live happily ever after

Comment: @yuvi: `unicodecsv` doesn't support UTF-16 or UTF-32, the `unicode_csv_reader()` trick does.

Comment: True, though personally I always found utf-8 (and thereby unicodecsv) to be sufficient enough